# Not able to trace GA event tracking code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

```
<a href="#interiors" onclick="dataLayer.push({'category':'Specification Page','action':'Click','label':'Interiors','event':'Event Specification Page'});">Click here</a>
```

I have added Google Analytics event tracking code on the click event    of anchor "Click here". 
I have installed Google Analytics Debugger    extension for chrome browser to trace GA code. Rest of the GA code    execution is logged in the console,but,I am not able to see any log    for above event. Is there anything,I am missing in above code?
I have integrated both the codes on my page.And placement is in head section of page.

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','XXXXXXXX');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->


    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'XXXXXXXX', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the things in order:

1.- The pasted code belongs to Google Tag Manager, if you use that plataform to install Google Analytics, remmember create the tag  first and use preview mode to debbug it.

To enable the degbug mode on GTM you have to follow the next steps

[image: GTM PREVIEW MODE]

When it's enable you can see a debugger on the bottom 
[image: GTM DEBUG ON]

2.- If you install directly Google Analytics on your domain, you have used the wrong sintaxis, in that case you have to change the way to tack the events, to recognize if you use the GA main snippet, look for if the code below is pasted on you html code.

```js
 <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

If that is the case, use the following sintaxis

```html
    <a href="#interiors" onclick="ga('send', 'category', 'action', 'label');">Click here</a>
```

I recommend you the [GA Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna), this is available on Chrome

If you use the GA Debugger, you have to inizialice the tools click on the icon 
[image: GA DEBUGGER ON] and open the javascript console (in chrome  + windows you can use f12 to open the console and ESC to open the javascipt console) to see the GA actions.
[image]

Comment: Hi Kemen,
Thank you for your answer.I have edited my question & added GTM & Google analytics code in it which was available in page.